# In Bot Framework Web Chat, how do I connect to my bot server?

Tags: botframework

All the tutorial are connecting to direct line, what about using my own bot server?  How do I connect in javascript?

I already setup server side:

```
// Setup BotFramework
var connector = new Builder.ChatConnector({

    appId: "a8...",
    appPassword: "ko...",
    openIdMetadata: process.env.BotOpenIdMetadata

});

// Setup Bot
var bot = new Builder.UniversalBot(connector);
bot.set('storage', new Builder.MemoryBotStorage());
// Setup Server
var server = Restify.createServer();

server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 4000, function () {
    console.log("Listening on port "+(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 4000));
});
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());
```

On the client side, here is what I currently got using direct line:

```
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/CognitiveServices.js"></script>

<script>
    const params = BotChat.queryParams(location.search);

    const speechOptions = {
        speechRecognizer: new BotChat.Speech.BrowserSpeechRecognizer(),
        speechSynthesizer: new BotChat.Speech.BrowserSpeechSynthesizer()
    };


    BotChat.App({
        showUploadButton: false,
        directLine: { secret: '_bm...' },
        bot: { id: 'a8...' },
        locale: params['locale'],
        resize: 'detect',
        speechOptions: speechOptions,
        user: {
            id: 'WebChatDemoUser',
            name: 'You'
        },
    }, document.getElementById('ChatBot'));
    var header = document.getElementsByClassName("wc-header");
    header[0].innerHTML = "<span>Chat</span>"
</script>
```

So this work, but it connect directly to the bot framework, I need to connect to my server like this:

```
http://localhost:4000/api/messages
```

Or on production would be like this:

```
http://myserver.com:4000/api/messages
```

Basically, similar to how Bot Emulator connect:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**DirectLineJs** will call the **Direct Line Connector Service** by default.  The connector service then calls your bot, and the bot calls back to the connector service with responses (or proactive messages).  **DirectLineJs** does provide a domain parameter you can supply to override the default:

```
const dl = new DirectLine({
    secret: /* put your Direct Line secret here */,
    token: /* or put your Direct Line token here (supply secret OR token, not both) */,
    domain: /* optional: if you are not using the default Direct Line endpoint, e.g. if you are using a region-specific endpoint, put its full URL here */
    webSocket: /* optional: false if you want to use polling GET to receive messages. Defaults to true (use WebSocket). */,
    pollingInterval: /* optional: set polling interval in milliseconds. Default to 1000 */,
});
```

However, there is a lot more involved in hosting your own **Direct Line Connector Service**.  The SDK code will use the activity's ***serviceUrl*** property to send messages back to the connector service.  The bot is expecting endpoints such as those in this MockChannelController: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/blob/master/blog-samples/CSharp/MockChannel/Controllers/MockChannelController.cs

More details are explained in this **Load Testing** blog post: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/19/load-testing-a-bot/

There's also this limited node example: [offline-directline](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS#create-a-directline-object)